# DOMParser()したオブジェクトでquerySelector()を行うと結果がnullになる

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Webページをfetchして、特定のセレクターの内容を取得したいです。
しかし、下記のコードを実行すると、domTargetがnullとなります。
どうすればセレクターの内容を取得できるのでしょうか。

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});

async function clickHandler(e) {
    const data = await fetch('https://www.google.com/search?q=a')
    const html = data.text()
    const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    const domTarget = dom.querySelector('#result-stats')
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="search.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn">RUN</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
{
    "name": "Sample",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "content.html"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問文のmanifest.jsonには`host_permissions`が設定されていないのでその時点でCORSエラーとなってそうですが、それを

```
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://www.google.com/"
    ]
```

としたうえで。

---

```
    const data = await fetch('https://www.google.com/search?q=a')
    const html = data.text()
```

とされていますが、この[Response.text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Response/text)は非同期的に解決される、すなわち`Promise`を返します。なので、awaitする必要があります。

```
async function clickHandler(e) {
    const data = await fetch('https://www.google.com/search?q=a')
    const html = await data.text()
    const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    const domTarget = dom.querySelector('#result-stats')
    console.log(domTarget)
}
```

[image: domTarget]